# Does pandas.read_csv loads all data at once?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know when I use `pandas.read_csv('file.csv')` function to read `csv` file, did it load all data of `file.csv` into `DataFrame`?

Comment: The default behaviour is to read the whole file.

Comment: As chthonicdaemon said the default behaviour is to read the whole file, but we  can use the parameter 'chunksize' to get a i TextFileReader iterator to get contents for certain lines

Answer (score 0):

The way to check is `len(df)`. This will give you the number of lines in `DataFrame.`  Then, you need to check the `csv` file for lines. On linux, use `wc -l`. Or, you may need to use something else to findout lines in csv. `Notepad++, Nano, SumlineText.`

Comment: Thanks, this method can help me to identify the rows once loaded,